# How to Convert "space" into "%20" with R

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

Referring the title, I'm figuring how to convert space between words to be %20 .

For example,

```
> y <- "I Love You"
```

How to make `y = I%20Love%20You`

```
> y
[1] "I%20Love%20You"
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gsub()` is one option:

```
R> gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "%20", x = y)
[1] "I%20Love%20You"
```

Answer (score 23):

Another option would be `URLencode()`:

```
y <- "I love you"
URLencode(y)
[1] "I%20love%20you"
```

Comment: +1 Better than my Answer and a good reminder of this function's existance

Comment: Important to note that this only replaces " " with %20, if you need to convert others, `RCurl::curlEscape()` is better.

Comment: @AmitKohli if you need to convert other characters (such as ```!$&'()*+,;=:/?@#[] ```) you can also use `URLencode` with argument `reserved` set to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

The function `curlEscape()` from the package `RCurl` gets the job done.

```
library('RCurl')
y <- "I love you"
curlEscape(urls=y)
[1] "I%20love%20you"
```

Comment: Note that this will change "test!: " to "test%21%3A%20"
vs URLencode "test!%3a%20"

Answer (score 1):

I like `URLencode()` but be aware that sometimes it does not work as expected if your url already contains a `%20` together with a real space, in which case not even the `repeated` option of `URLencode()` is doing what you want.

In my case, I needed to run both `URLencode()` and `gsub` consecutively to get exactly what I needed, like so:

```
a = "already%20encoded%space/a real space.csv"

URLencode(a)
#returns: "encoded%20space/real space.csv"
#note the spaces that are not transformed

URLencode(a, repeated=TRUE)
#returns: "encoded%2520space/real%20space.csv"
#note the %2520 in the first part

gsub(" ", "%20", URLencode(a))
#returns: "encoded%20space/real%20space.csv"
```

In this particular example, `gsub()` alone would have been enough, but `URLencode()` is of course doing more than just replacing spaces.